# Изменение цвета строки в таблице по выбранному статусу

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, ajax

Всем привет
Есть таблица, в которой вывожу данные о работе сотрудников тех. отдела

у меня есть отдельная таблица в бд со статусами, кол-во статусов 9, сначала добавляю инцидент в таблицу, потом когда надо меняю статус инцидента, и вот хочу чтоб при выборе определенного статуса менять цвет строчки, подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать скрипт, в форуме есть похожие темы, но тут во многих случаях по клику меняют цвет и т.д.

```html
<table>
           <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Инцидент добавлен</th>
                        <th>Агент</th>
                        <th>Количество заявок</th>
                        <th>Номера терминалов</th>
                        <th>Примечание</th>
                        <th>Статус</th>
                        <th>Регион</th>
                        <th>Дата изменения инцидента</th>
                        <th>Специалист</th>
                        <th>Редактирование</th>
                    </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <?php foreach($tasks as $task):?> //вывожу циклом данные из бд
 
                    <tr>
                        <td><?= $task["id"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $task["date"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $task["title"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $task["content"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $task["amount"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $task["comment"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $task["status"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $task["region"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $task["change_time"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $task["spe******t"]; ?></td>
 
                        <td class="btn-all">
                            <a href="show.php?id=<?= $task['id'];?>" class="btn-show">Show</a>
                            <a href="edit.php?id=<?= $task['id'];?>" class="btn-edit">Edit</a>
                            <a onclick="return confirm('Вы уверены, что хотите удалить инцидент?');" href="delete.php?id=<?= $task['id'];?>" class="btn-delete">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
 
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так это можно сделать. https://codepen.io/latdev/pen/xxXZrbQ

```js
document.getElementById("statusSelect").addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  let status_id = event.target.value;
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".status-all")].forEach(e => e.style.backgroundColor = '');
  if (status_id !== "none") {
    [...document.querySelectorAll(".status-"+status_id)].forEach(e => e.style.backgroundColor = 'pink');
  }
});
```

В каждый tr добавляешь классы `class="status-all status-<?= $status_id ?>"` потом в JS чистишь все `status-all` и заполняешь цветом `status-XXX`

Comment: не совсем то, у меня у каждого инцидента будет свой статус, то есть есть инцидент после его выполнения я выбираю для него статус "Выполнено" и он должен закрашиваться в зеленый цвет

Comment: @BehruzBurov Ну не выполняй отчистку, просто проверяй статус и крась нужным цветом.